# How should I use Mono.zipWith when including a function that returns a Mono?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a `Mono` that I want to combine with another `Mono`, as in:

```
val firstMono = Mono.just("thing");
val secondMono = Mono.just("other thing");
val thirdMono = firstMono.zipWith(secondMono, function);
```

But I want the `function` to also return a `Mono`, *without* ending up with a `Mono<Mono<?>>`

The best I can come up with is:

```
val thirdMono = firstMono.zipWith(secondMono, function)
                          .flatMap(identity());
```

but that seems like a bit of a hack.

I also thought of

```
val thirdMono = firstMono.zipWith(secondMono)
                         .flatMap(function);
```

but in that case, I have to have the `function` accept a `Tuple2` instead of the individual arguments, which is uglier.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `val thirdMono = firstMono.zipWith(secondMono).flatMap(pair -> function(pair.getT1(), pair.getT2()));` ...

Comment: Yeah, I had that as well - works, but makes the `Mono` chain uglier... Likely, I'm looking for something that doesn't exist - some operator that recognises that I'm working with another `Mono`. `.flatZipWith` would've been nice...

Comment: I'd go with `var thirdMono =  firstMono.flatMap(left -> secondMono.flatMap(right -> function(left, right)));` but I guess it's arguable whether this is in any way "prettier".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your solution is good enough.

If you think that it seems like hack, you could place it in a separate utility method and change it when you find the better solution. Something like:

```
private static  <T1, T2, O> Function<Mono<T1>, Publisher<O>> flatZipTransformer(
        Mono<T2> p2, BiFunction<T1, T2, Mono<O>> function) {
    return p1 -> Mono.zip(p1, p2, function).flatMap(Function.identity());
}
```

Now you could use it like:

```
firstMono.transform(flatZipTransformer(secondMono, function))
```

Comment: Thanks - I think I’ll stick with my `flatMap(identity())` solution then - just wanted to know if I was missing something...